# React app crashes when loading Redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am currently getting into **React, Redux and Typescript** and I am still kinda new to them. The application I made was purely for learning Redux.
 It is a simple searchbox which should update the store
However, when I try to load the AppStore in my component, the application crashes.

**The Redux App**

```
import { Action, Reducer, createStore, Store } from 'redux';

export enum ActionTypes { UPDATE_FILTER_STRING, CLEAR_FILTER_STRING }
export interface FilterStringActions extends Action {
    type: ActionTypes;
    value: string;
}

export const createUpdateFilterStringAction: (_filterString: string) => FilterStringActions = (_filterString) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_FILTER_STRING,
    value: _filterString
});
export const createClearFilterStringAction: () => FilterStringActions = () => ({
    type: ActionTypes.CLEAR_FILTER_STRING,
    value: ""
});

export interface AppState {
    filterString: string;
}
export const reducer: Reducer<AppState> = (state: AppState = { filterString: "" }, action: FilterStringActions) => {
    const newState: AppState = ({
        filterString: action.value
    });
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.UPDATE_FILTER_STRING:
            return newState;
        case ActionTypes.CLEAR_FILTER_STRING:
            newState.filterString = "";
            return newState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export var appStore: Store<AppState> = createStore<AppState>(reducer);
```

**My Container Component** (interacts with redux/smart component) containing "dumb" components

```
import * as React from 'react';
import SPSearchBox from './SPSearchBox';
import { Store } from 'redux';
import * as ReduxApp from './Redux-App';

export interface IComponentsContainerProps {
  description: string;
}

export interface IComponentsContainerState {
  SearchString: String;
  store: Store<ReduxApp.AppState>;
}

export default class ComponentsContainer extends React.Component<IComponentsContainerProps, IComponentsContainerState> {
  private unsubscribe: Function;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      SearchString: "",
      store: ReduxApp.appStore
    };
    // this.onSearchStringChanged = this.onSearchStringChanged.bind(this);
  };

  // public componentDidMount() {
  //   this.unsubscribe = this.props.store.subscribe(() => {
  //     this.setState({
  //       SearchString: this.props.store.getState().filterString
  //     });
  //   });
  // };

  // public componentWillUnmount() {
  //   this.unsubscribe();
  // };

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IComponentsContainerProps> {
    return (<SPSearchBox />);
  };
}
```

If I remove the line that sets my store in the state, my app runs:

```
this.state = {
      SearchString: "",
      store: ReduxApp.appStore //<======= This line breaks code
    };
```

**The Error**

> [SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:: Unable to load web part
>   WebPart.FabricReduxWebPart.77c43a83-9506-4645-83f1-d930de78a55c,Error:
>   ***Failed to load component "a1d9e197-3ac8-4594-92b9-bac4b92086e8" (FabricReduxWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load entry point
>   from component "a1d9e197-3ac8-4594-92b9-bac4b92086e8"
>   (FabricReduxWebPart). script resources due to: {1}. CALLSTACK:: Error
>   at SPWebPartError.SPError [as constructor]
>   (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader_en-us.js:13577:26)
>   at new SPWebPartError
>   (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-base/dist/sp-webpart-base_en-us.js:988:30)
>   at Function.SPWebPartError.create
>   (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-base/dist/sp-webpart-base_en-us.js:1012:18)
>   at
>   https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-base/dist/sp-webpart-base_en-us.js:1884:65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the problem.. 

**The solution** (Drum sounds...)

> running **gulp clean** solved the exceptions

Another amazing day of solving complicated problems.

Lol